# Missing code-signing certificate even with valid linked certificate

Tags: ios, xamarin

I followed the [instructions](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/testflight/) at Xamarin for uploading my app for testing with TestFlight.

So basically I have developer certificate registered in my Keychain and it is linked with the Provisioning profile and it has the App ID set to the bundle id of the iOS project.

Once I start the uploading process via the Application Loader I always get the ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisoning profile included in the bundle xxxx is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.]

Even though my provisioning profile is linked to my developer certificate I still get the missing code-signing certifiate.

I am using Visual Studio to build the iOS project using the ad-hoc configuration. My Mac is running Yosemite and I have the latest stable releases of Xamarin.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you including extensions at all in your app? If so, try just archiving your application, then right click on the archive you created (from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/{the date}/ -> Show Package Contents, open up Products/Applications then right click on your .app -> Show Package Contents, search for the iTunesMetadata.plist file and drag that to the trash, then re-submit the same archive and you should be successful. It's most likely an issue with Xamarin Studio not being able to sign extensions correctly.

Comment: Hi @chrisntr thanks for your quick reply. I am not using any extensions. What I forgot to mention is that I am building my iOS app in Visual Studio using the Ad-Hoc configuration with bundle signing set accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think you should be using the ad-hoc configuration if you're trying to put your app through on the app store, you would probably need to give a bit more of an overview on what settings you have to help out any further, otherwise it just sounds like you're trying to build the app with the wrong configuration

Comment: I am using ad-hoc configuration because I am preparing it for testing. But I also tried choosing the appstore configuration and had the same problem. I was following the steps over here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/ipa_support_for_ad_hoc_and_enterprise_deployment/#Installing_an_IPA_using_iTunes